# PHP form generating from multiple databases and cross referencing

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to use PHP to generate a form from multiple databases. I want to set it up like a table so for instance the headers along the top would be pulled from one database and the first column would be pulled from another.

The rest of the cells in the table are inputs, so say if the first two databases contained letters and numbers you would end up with something like this:

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>c</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I then want to store the inputs in a new table so I'd be able to cross reference them like a3, b1, etc,.

The issue is I do not have a set number of values in the first two tables so they can go up to approx 15 items. I was trying to figure out what the best way to achieve this would be.

I think I am going to have to do some sort of nested loop to get the numbers of rows and columns I will need.

### Edit

So what I'm trying to achieve is advanced pricing for an e-commerce store.

The first table `countries` is a list of countries that we sell to with the currency symbol, vat rates etc,.

[image]

The second table `attributes` has different options for the products that we sell such as colour, size, etc,.

[image]

So what I want then is more like this with the £,€,$ symbols coming from the countries table

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>attribute name</td>
      <td>country name 1</td>
      <td>country name 2</td>
      <td>country name 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>attribute option 1</td>
      <td>£<input type="text"></td>
      <td>€<input type="text"></td>
      <td>$<input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>attribute option 2</td>
      <td>£<input type="text"></td>
      <td>€<input type="text"></td>
      <td>$<input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>attribute option 3</td>
      <td>£<input type="text"></td>
      <td>€<input type="text"></td>
      <td>$<input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the concept of what you're trying to achieve (especially pulling from multiple dbs). Can you share the table structure so I can get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: @bos570 sorry it's kind of a weird one to explain what I'm trying to achieve, I hope my edit above makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Ideally you would build in that relationship in the db. I'm not exactly sure what it would be in your case just because I'm missing info but you can do something like this:

```
$attributeResult = //Db results from query for attributes
$countriesResult - //Db resultf fro query for coutnrties
foreach ($attributeResult as $value) {
   echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>'; 
   foreach ($countryResult as $countryVal) {
       echo '<td>'.$countryVal['currency'].'<input /></td>'
   }
}
```

Again, this is very generic based on the info you provided but conceptually this is what you can do to get desired results.

Comment: Sure, here to help if you need any more direction.